# Is this a valid C ifdef structure? Is there a better way?

Tags: c, syntax

I want to add a new file format into my project. So I am `#define`ing a new file format type, but I want to keep support for the old format too.

Does my setup/structure of `#ifdef`s and `#else`s make sense, is it valid? I'm pretty sure it is, but I feel without braces it doesn't make sense.

```
// My intention
if()
   ;
else
{
    if()
        ;
    else
        ;
}
```

.

```
#ifdef FILE_FORMAT_TWO
    sprintf(xxx); 
#else
    #ifdef NEW_FILE_FORMAT
        sprintf(xxx); 
    #else
        sprintf(xxx);
    #endif
        sprintf(xxx);
#endif
```

Is there a prettier way to do this?

EDIT: What I mean to say, is the first section of code is what I mean to do with the `#`(pound defines, ifs, and elses) in the second section. I was not sure if the second section read the same as the first. I wrote the second section as such because I didn't realize to use `#elif`, I was missing that piece of information.

Comment: Doing it with `#ifdef`s means that one version of your program can't support both file formats, you would need to have a separate version for each format.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to make this a compile-time condition? Why not just use normal `if`s and figure it out at runtime?

Comment: The question looks vague. But if you actually ask whether to pick version 1 or 2, I will say version 1. The second version is processed at compile time (actually preprocessing) while you probably want to select the format depending on the file (at run time).

Comment: That works.  Of course most editors will insist on left-aligning the `#` signs, mucking up your pretty formatting, and that final `sprintf` will be executed for both old and new file format.

Comment: Ahhh, I think what I was missing is the `#elif`, not sure how many times I tried `#else if` or `#elseif`, I just figured it wasn't supported. ----- Also I put an edit in the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#ifdef FILE_FORMAT_TWO
    sprintf(xxx); 
#elif defined(NEW_FILE_FORMAT)
    sprintf(xxx); 
#else
    sprintf(xxx);
#endif
```

And here is an explanation. The C pre-processor directives permit you to use `#ifdef` as a shortform for `#if defined`. The Gnu C compiler's pre-processor directives can be found [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/).  That document is somewhat long, so the portion that pertains to conditional syntax lies [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Conditional-Syntax.html#Conditional-Syntax).

In general though, I've found it cleaner to be explicit in my pre-processing directives, like so:

```
#if defined(FILE_FORMAT_TWO)
    sprintf(xxx); 
#elif defined(NEW_FILE_FORMAT)
    sprintf(xxx); 
#elif defined(DEFAULT_FILE_FORMAT)
    sprintf(xxx);
#else
#error "You must define blah blah"
#endif
```

Credits to Jonathan Leffler for pointing out the stylistic inconsistency in `#ifdef FILE_FORMAT_TWO` and suggesting replacement with `#if defined (FILE_FORMAT_TWO)`

Answer (score 3):

```
#ifdef FILE_FORMAT_TWO
    sprintf(xxx); 
#else
    #ifdef NEW_FILE_FORMAT
        sprintf(xxx); 
    #else
        sprintf(xxx);
    #endif
        sprintf(xxx);     <<---- remove this
#endif
```

But I think that it would be better something like:

```
#define FILE_FORMAT 1
```

and

```
#if FILEFORMAT == 1

#elif FILEFORMAT == 2

#else

#endif
```